# Why is enabling Google+ API in Google Console neccessary for Spring Social Google - version 1.0.0 RELEASE?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-social, spring-social-google

It's a spring boot project that uses spring social dependencies for configuring Google sso. When using one version of spring-social-google it works perfectly, upon updating the version it stops working.

I've used Spring Social Google version 1.0.0 RC1 without having to enable Google+ API in order for sso to work. Upon switching to version 1.0.0 RELEASE, sso stopped working. The only solution I came upon was enabling Google+ API in the Google console.

```
    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-social-google</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.RC1</version>
</dependency>
```

```
    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-social-google</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Why is Google+ required in order for simple google sign on to work with spring-social and spring-social-google? 
Thanks